# Do Elementary Events are always mutually exclusive

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

It might be simple question, But I'm having a little doubt because of one statement in a book.

**Elementary Events**

In probability theory, an elementary event (atomic event) is an event which contains only a single outcome in the sample space.

**Example**: {HH}, {HT}, {TH} and {TT} are elementary events, if a coin is tossed twice.

Do Elementary events are always mutually exclusive. I think they will always be mutually exclusive. But I was reading `CLRS` and one statement confused me.

> For any event A,
>
> $P\{A\} = {\sum}_{s \in A} P\{s\}$
>
> since elementary events, specifically those in A, are mutually exclusive. [Page-1191]

They didn't give a specific example when it'll be not. Can anybody clear my little doubt.

Comment: What is `CLRS`?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Introduction to Algorithms-CLRS

Comment: I repeat: What is CLRS? (Nevermind, I googled it).  You'll find a broader audience of answerers if you avoid abbreviations.

Comment: Well, $\{x\}\cap\{y\}=\emptyset$ if $x \neq y$, obviously

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic why they have used the word `specifically` in the statement. See above

Comment: Every family of elementary events is a family of mutually exclusive events. In particular, this is the case for the family $B=\{ \{s\} \mid s \in A\}$ of all elementary sets contained in $A$. We are specifically interested in this family because $\bigcup_{E \in B} E=A$ and we can conclude that $$P(A)=\sum_{E \in B} P(E)=\sum_{s \in A} P\{s\}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found It is true that

> Elementary events are always mutually exclusive